# Pointing the camera in a particular direction programmatically

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Python to place a camera. I know the camera's location, and the forward and up vectors for the camera (i.e. the direction it's pointing and its orientation). How do I do this?

I know that it's possible to calculate a raw world matrix from the above information, which I can then apply to the camera, but I was rather hoping not to have to. Is there an easier way?

Comment: do you want to set the cameras direction in the game engine?

Comment: No, I'm writing a script to create a scene with the camera in a specific location.

Answer (score 33):

Heres a script to make a camera point towards any point in space.

```
import bpy

def look_at(obj_camera, point):
    loc_camera = obj_camera.matrix_world.to_translation()

    direction = point - loc_camera
    # point the cameras '-Z' and use its 'Y' as up
    rot_quat = direction.to_track_quat('-Z', 'Y')

    # assume we're using euler rotation
    obj_camera.rotation_euler = rot_quat.to_euler()

# Test
obj_camera = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
obj_other = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

obj_camera.location = (5.0, 2.0, 3.0)
look_at(obj_camera, obj_other.matrix_world.to_translation())
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand this --- the docs for `to_track_quat()` are... brief. I don't see how the fixed axis parameters get rotated to point in my desired direction. (When I say I have the location and forward and up vectors, I mean _literally_ I have a Point and two Vector objects.) Can you expand?

Comment: The camera starts off pointing along the -Z axis with the top of the camera pointing along the +Y axis. The variable "direction" is the vector from the camera to the point. The function direction.to_track_quat('-Z', 'Y') returns the quaternion that rotates '-Z' so that it aligns with the direction vector. This rotation is not unique because the rotated camera can still rotate about direction vector. Specifying Y gives the rotation quaternion with the -Z vector aligned with the direction vector and the Y vector pointing up.

Comment: You might want to call `bpy.context.scene.update()` after changing the camera's location to make sure the matrix is up to date.

Comment: +1 for @Daerst 's suggestion to update the scene, this fixed things for me. However, in Blender 2.8+ you'll need ```bpy.context.view_layer.update()``` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a version of [ideasman42's look_at function](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5220/12947)
that also allows you to roll the camera (or any object) about the axis from camera to target:

```
def point_at(obj, target, roll=0):
    """
    Rotate obj to look at target

    :arg obj: the object to be rotated. Usually the camera
    :arg target: the location (3-tuple or Vector) to be looked at
    :arg roll: The angle of rotation about the axis from obj to target in radians. 

    Based on: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5220/12947 (ideasman42)      
    """
    if not isinstance(target, mathutils.Vector):
        target = mathutils.Vector(target)
    loc = obj.location
    # direction points from the object to the target
    direction = target - loc
    tracker, rotator = (('-Z', 'Y'),'Z') if obj.type=='CAMERA' else (('X', 'Z'),'Y') #because new cameras points down(-Z), usually meshes point (-Y)
    quat = direction.to_track_quat(*tracker)
    
    # /usr/share/blender/scripts/addons/add_advanced_objects_menu/arrange_on_curve.py
    quat = quat.to_matrix().to_4x4()
    rollMatrix = mathutils.Matrix.Rotation(roll, 4, rotator)

    # remember the current location, since assigning to obj.matrix_world changes it
    loc = loc.to_tuple()
    #obj.matrix_world = quat * rollMatrix
    # in blender 2.8 and above @ is used to multiply matrices
    # using * still works but results in unexpected behaviour!
    obj.matrix_world = quat @ rollMatrix
    obj.location = loc
```

It can be used like this:

```
import math
cube = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]
cube.location = (5, -5, 5)
cam = bpy.data.objects["Camera"]
cam.location = (5, -5, -2)
point_at(cam, cube.location, roll=math.radians(45))
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

One way is to assign tuples directly to the camera object's [`location`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location) and [`rotation_euler`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_3/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.rotation_euler) attributes. For example, with the camera selected:

```
import bpy
from math import radians

camera = bpy.context.object
camera.location = (1.0, 0.0, 1.0)
camera.rotation_euler = (radians(45), 0.0, radians(30))
```