# how to perform an inplane (tilt) rotation of the camera?

Tags: rendering

Is (how) it possible to perform an inplane (tilt) rotation of the camera for rendering? [image: Visual description]
With the "Rotation" Tab in the Transform section, I wasn´t able to get it work correctly. Can somebody help?

Comment: Ok I figured it out :) If somebody has a similar problem: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5210/pointing-the-camera-in-a-particular-direction-programmatically/5220